# Ionic, how to set android:largeHeap="true"

Tags: ionic-framework

how to set **android:largeHeap="true"** in Ionic project?

I'm using Ionic v.1.2.4

[Edited]

Is there any way to set without modifying the manifest file directly, setting in Ionic layer?

Because the manifest file is generated by Ionic build, so I don't want to touch that autogenerated file directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to the manifest like this

```
<application
     android:largeHeap="true">
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your manifest file....under the `<application>`section you can add `android:largeHeap="true"`
 For better understanding please [refere](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) this from developers guide